# Erlang Tcp Accepter Pattern

Tags: tcp, erlang

Consider the following (based on sockserv from LYSE)

```
%%% The supervisor in charge of all the socket acceptors.
-module(tcpsocket_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0, start_socket/0]).
-export([init/1]).

start_link() ->
  supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->
  {ok, Port} = application:get_env(my_app,tcpPort),
  {ok, ListenSocket} = gen_tcp:listen(
    Port,
    [binary, {packet, 0}, {reuseaddr, true}, {active, true} ]),
  lager:info(io_lib:format("Listening for TCP on port ~p", [Port])),
  spawn_link(fun empty_listeners/0),
  {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, 60, 3600},
    [{socket,
      {tcpserver, start_link, [ListenSocket]},
      temporary, 1000, worker, [tcpserver]}
    ]}}.

start_socket() ->
  supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, []).%,

empty_listeners() ->
  [start_socket() || _ <- lists:seq(1,20)],
  ok.
```

---

```
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% @author mylesmcdonnell
%%% @copyright (C) 2015, <COMPANY>
%%% @doc
%%%
%%% @end
%%% Created : 06. Feb 2015 07:49
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------
-module(tcpserver).
-author("mylesmcdonnell").

-behaviour(gen_server).

-record(state, {
    next,
    socket}).

-export([start_link/1]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, code_change/3, terminate/2]).

-define(SOCK(Msg), {tcp, _Port, Msg}).
-define(TIME, 800).
-define(EXP, 50).

start_link(Socket) ->
  gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, Socket, []).

init(Socket) ->
  gen_server:cast(self(), accept),
  {ok, #state{socket=Socket}}.

handle_call(_E, _From, State) ->
  {noreply, State}.

handle_cast(accept, S = #state{socket=ListenSocket}) ->
  {ok, AcceptSocket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket),
  kvstore_tcpsocket_sup:start_socket(),
  receive
    {tcp, Socket, <<"store",Value/binary>>} ->
      Uid = kvstore:store(Value),
      send(Socket,Uid);
    {tcp, Socket, <<"retrieve",Key/binary>>} ->
      case kvstore:retrieve(binary_to_list(Key)) of
        [{_, Value}|_] ->
          send(Socket,Value);
        _ ->
          send(Socket,<<>>)
      end;
    {tcp, Socket, _} ->
      send(Socket, "INVALID_MSG")
  end,
  {noreply, S#state{socket=AcceptSocket, next=name}}.

handle_info(_, S) ->
  {noreply, S}.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
  {ok, State}.

terminate(normal, _State) ->
  ok;
terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
  lager:info("terminate reason: ~p~n", [_Reason]).

send(Socket, Bin) ->
  ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, Bin),
  ok = gen_tcp:close(Socket),
  ok.
```

I'm unclear on how each tcpserver process is terminated? Is this leaking processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any place that you are terminating the owning process.

I think what you are looking for are four cases:

- The client terminates the connection (you receive `tcp_closed`)
- The connection goes wonky (you receive `tcp_error`)
- The server receives a system message to terminate (this could, of course, just be the supervisor killing it, or a kill message)
- The client sends a message telling the server its done and you want to do some clean up other than just reacting to `tcp_closed`.

The most common case is usually the client just closes the connection, and for that you want something like:

```
handle_info({tcp_closed, _}, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State};
```

The connection getting weird is always a possibility. I can't think of any time I want to have the owning process or the socket stick around, so:

```
%% You might want to log something here.
handle_info({tcp_error, _}, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State};
```

And any case where the client tells the server its done and you need to do cleanup based on the client having done something successful (maybe you have resources open that should be written to first, or a pending DB transaction open, or whatever) you would want to expect a success message from the client that closes the connection the way your `send/2` does, and returns `{stop, normal, State}` to halt the process.

The key here is making sure you identify the cases where you want to end the connection and either have the server process killed or (better) return `{stop, Reason, State}`.

As written above, if you intend `send/2` to be a single response and a clean exit (or really, that every `accept` cast should result in a single `send/2` and then termination), then you want:

```
handle_cast(accept, S = #state{socket=ListenSocket}) ->
  {ok, AcceptSocket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket),
  kvstore_tcpsocket_sup:start_socket(),
  receive
    %% stuff that results in a call to send/2 in any case.
  end,
  {stop, normal, S}.
```

The case LYSE demonstrates is one where the connection is persistent and there is ongoing back-and-forth between a client and server. In the case above you are handling a single request, spawning a new listener to re-fill the listener pool, and should be exiting because you have no plan of this gen_server doing any further work.